# SwiftUI setting status bar style

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios13, xcode11

I have been attempting to set the statusbar in my SwiftUI app to light text as it has a dark background.

I found this solution on several sites but cannot get it to work.

HostingController.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class HostingController : UIHostingController {
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
    }
}
```

This returns an error on the class declaration line `Reference to generic type 'UIHostingController' requires arguments in <...>` with a suggested fix of `Insert '<<#Content: View#>>'`.  Applying said fix results in the error `Use of undeclared type '<#Content: View#>'`

You are then meant to change the `window.rootViewController` in the `SceneDelegate.swift` file.

SceneDelegate.swift

...

```
// Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = Login()

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = HostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
```

...

This throws an error on the `window.rootViewController` line `Argument passed to call that takes no arguments`

Anyone got any ideas?  Seems like a lot of bother just to set the status bar colour which I imagine would be a fairly common requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 14 you just need to change/add 2 keys in Info.plist:

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer as of iOS 14.  There is no longer any requirement to code this in.  Change the settings as indicated above in the `Info.plist` file.

Comment: Here's a video showing how to update the Info.plist:
https://youtu.be/w-I5I8POMSI

Comment: That works nice and clean! Please note, that this will change the status bar for the whole app. If you need to change it on a view basis you may want to check out this: https://github.com/xavierdonnellon/swiftui-statusbarstyle

Answer (score 6):

Your HostingController needs a concrete type of the rootView:

```
class HostingViewController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content> {

    @objc override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

Then use it in `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo...` as the rootViewController:

```
let contentView = ContentView()
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        
        window.rootViewController = HostingViewController(rootView: AnyView(contentView.environmentObject(SessionStore())))
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

You won't see any difference in canvas unfortunately, but try it on a simulator.

Comment: Thanks.  This works.  However I have to remove my `environmentObject` to make it work `HostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(SessionStore())` otherwise it requires fixing to `HostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(SessionStore()) as! ContentView)` which then throws a `SIGABRT` error when run.

Comment: Try declaring like this: HostingViewController: UIHostingController<AnyView> and then erasing your rootview to AnyView  HostingController(rootView: AnyView(contentView.environmentObject(SessionStore())))

Comment: `window.rootViewController = AnyView HostingController(rootView: AnyView(contentView.environmentObject(SessionStore())))` throws the error `Cannot assign value of type 'AnyView.Type' to type 'UIViewController?'`

Comment: It's not quite what I had in mind. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Works like a charm `window.rootViewController = HostingController(rootView: AnyView(contentView.environmentObject(SessionStore())))`

Comment: I'm a bit late, but you can use generics better:

Answer (score 6):

Another way to extend `UIHostingController` is to keep the generic `Content` type, then you don't have to pass the session store:

```
class HostingController<Content>: UIHostingController<Content> where Content: View {
    @objc override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

then in your scene delegate:

```
window.rootViewController = HostingController(rootView: contentView)
```

Comment: This works awesome. My issue was the some: View and onTapGesture wouldn't work unless the generics were correct as above. I also didn't need the @objc.
Which let me also do:
```
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = HostingController(
                rootView: homeView.onTapGesture {
                    window.endEditing(true)
                }
            )
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but you can use generics better:

```
class HostingController<ContentView: View>: UIHostingController<ContentView> {
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .darkContent
    }
}
```

This allows you to pass any view to the HostingController even with .environmentObject() view modifier.