# How to change the status bar background color in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `ZStack` which has `Color.orange` set on it:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.orange
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange
            TabView {
                Settings()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                    Text("Settings")
                }
                MapKitView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "location.circle.fill")
                    Text("Home")
                }
                ProfileView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                    Text("Profile")
                }
            }
            .font(.headline)
        }
    }
}
```

and in this `ZStack` I have a `TabView` with child views that all have orange `ZStacks`. However these child views, including `Settings()` and `MapKitView()` shown below, do not have an orange status bar.

**Settings()**

```
struct Settings: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange
            VStack {
                NavigationView {
                       ...
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MapKitView()**

```
struct MapKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        return mapView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapKitView>) {

    }
}
```

[image]

How can I make the status bar orange across all my views?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: Status bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063142/swiftui-status-bar-color)

Comment: No it doesn't that just changes the text not background colour @pawello2222

Comment: You should use `Color.orange.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` that way it should expand to fill the area that is not coverd.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```swift
ZStack {
...
}
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical) // or .top
```

`.edgesIgnoreSafeArea` is deprecated in iOS 14 and replaced with [`.ignoresSafeArea`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/ignoressafearea(_:edges:))

```swift
ZStack {
...
}
.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: [.bottom, .top])
```

Answer (score 20):

If, for example, you wanted to draw a nice blur under the status bar.

```swift
YourView()
    .overlay(alignment: .top) {
        Color.clear // Or any view or color
            .background(.regularMaterial) // I put clear here because I prefer to put a blur in this case. This modifier and the material it contains are optional.
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
            .frame(height: 0) // This will constrain the overlay to only go above the top safe area and not under.
    }
```

[image: A screenshot of the iOS simulator where an app with a map is shown and the device's status bar has a blur background.]

Comment: I like this! Works beautifully without using a ZStack. I suggest updating `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` to `.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)` given the recent deprecation :)