# How to change iOS status bar color per view without SceneDelegate using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios-statusbar

I have seen answers that solve the problem in the past using SceneDelegate which has now been removed with Swift's new lifecycle. Is there an updated solution to this problem?

Related oudated question: [SwiftUI: Status bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063142/swiftui-status-bar-color)

Changing iOS status bar color (time, cell phone coverage, wifi, etc) per view using SwiftUI.

Comment: Try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35287747/10564881

Comment: @RăzvanGabrielRujoiu The question I am asking is per view, not global