# Changing the status bar color based on @State SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am looking for a way to change the status bar color (time/service/battery) at the top of the screen based on a @State variable. I am using state to change different themes in my app. Some themes have a gray menu bar at the top and one has a black menu bar. When I switch to the black menu bar I can no longer see the status bar. Is there a way I can change that in my view based on the state? The app is written in SwiftUI and I am using a custom view modifier to change the styling based on state.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063142/swiftui-status-bar-color). Or if you feel lazy you can achieve the same result by playing around with the `appearences` in the colors in your `Assets.xcassets` with the help of `.preferredColorScheme(_:)`

Comment: I looked through that thread but from what I can tell those set the color as either black or white. I need it to change and adapt based on the state. If I set the `.preferredColorScheme(_:)` it changes the whole app to dark mode which I do not want. I am just trying to change the font color from black to white in the status bar.