# onOpenURL not called on iOS 15 simulator (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios15

I have a widget that opens my app via a custom url scheme (`myapp:some-deep-link`). In my app I have a handler setup like so:

```swift
var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            
            ContentView()
            .onOpenURL(perform: { url in
               //my code
            }
         }
     }
```

In iOS 14 this works perfectly, in iOS 15 (Simulator) `onOpenURL` is not called at all. The app launches, but there is no call. I am wondering if this might be a simulator problem or a bug or something I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: `onOpenURL` is working fine in my Widget to app, for iOS 15. Did you try and print the url to see if anything is called?

Comment: I put a breakpoint in the closure and it does not break. :( Do you also have other userActivity related methods applied to your content view?

Comment: In case someone has the same problem. If you used a workaround from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063142/swiftui-status-bar-color to change the status bar color and roll your own HostingController. That breaks onOpenURL. :(

Comment: I had the same problem.

Comment: oops... did anyone find a solution to this? Our designer would be really mad at us if we remove the status bar color!