# SceneDelegate.swift deprecated/changed architecture?

Tags: ios, swift

I am following alone with this tutorial to build my first Swift app: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRRS3xJnKBQ

[image: SceneDelegate.swift view]

As you can see above, at 6:21, they make some  changes to SceneDelegate.swift.

This file was not created in the tutorial.  And in my fresh XCode project, that file does not exist.

[image: My project]

The tutorial is 2 years old, so I'm wondering if Swift itself has changed since then or if I need to create that SceneDelegate.swift file.

Comment: @Sh_Khan so it goes in ContentView?

Comment: The thing he tried to do in this video just was changing status bar color into light. There is a new methods to do that. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063142/swiftui-status-bar-color