# Hide the Home Indicator in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm looking to hide the Home Indicator and while this is straightforward in Swift doesn't appear to be as easy in SwiftUI.

I attempted to use this:

[How to hide the home indicator with SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56795572/how-to-hide-the-home-indicator-with-swiftui)

But with the removal of the SceneDelegate I'm too green to know how to properly translate that for the new app protocol.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Dan

Comment: You can implement scene delegate in swuitui2.0

Comment: I posted an answer for you in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64623130/9497800

Answer (score 1):

Here is possible approach to replace default `WindowGroup` window's hosting controller with any custom one (in this case w/o home indicator).

The helper extension are taken from before provided solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63276688/12299030.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(MyAppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Text("")  // << temporary placeholder
                .withHostingWindow { window in
                    let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(SomeObservableObject())
                    window?.rootViewController = 
                         HideHomeIndicatorController(rootView: contentView)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

and simplified variant of hosting controller to hide home indicator

```
class HideHomeIndicatorController<Content:View>: UIHostingController<Content> {
    override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool {
        true
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is doing something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64623130/14348570 And I'm running into the same issue with both.  I'm totally green but it seems that in both cases it is replacing ContentView()?  I have several .environmentObject() initialized under a WindowGroup in the @main App that I think are therefore being skipped as a result?  (Sorry if that isn't quite what's happening but hopefully is the general gist.)

Comment: Read my comment to that post about pitfall. This solution is different - it only replaces root view controller in created window. See updated on how/where to inject environment object in this case.

Comment: Okay, I got that working for all views, is there a way to limit it to only affecting when in landscape?